# What browser does Ubuntu Touch use?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser

I was just wondering, what is the defualt web browser in Ubuntu phone.  I couldn't find it anywhere on the Internet.

Answer (score 6):

The browser app is the boringly named "webbrowser-app", from the [README](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~phablet-team/webbrowser-app/trunk/view/head:/README):

> webbrowser-app is a lightweight web browser tailored for Ubuntu,
>   based on the Webkit rendering engine and using the Ubuntu UI components.

Code is here:

- https://launchpad.net/webbrowser-app

Session from UDS is here (thanks [Radu](https://askubuntu.com/users/147044/radu-rdeanu)):

- http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-1303/meeting/21621/appdev-1303-apps-webbrowser/

Comment: It's called [Web Browser Application for touch devices](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-1303/meeting/21621/appdev-1303-apps-webbrowser/)

Comment: That's the title of the UDS session, I'll ask the author for a clarification.

Comment: ...they called it so.